# Google Test - undefined reference to testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I built Google Test from source on Windows 10. Now I'm trying to create an application that uses the library. Building the program with CMake fails for some reason.

EDIT // It seems that CMake is not linking Google Test properly. I get the same results when I remove the `target_link_libraries(tests GTest::GTest)` line from the tests folder CMakeLists.txt.

Here's my code (the program fails at the call to `EXPECT_EQ`):

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

namespace {
    class CanTest: public ::testing::Test {};

    TEST_F(CanTest, CanReallyTest) {
        EXPECT_EQ(0, 0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

Here's the tests subfolder CMakeLists.txt:

```
include(GoogleTest)
add_executable(tests CanTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests GTest::GTest)
gtest_discover_tests(tests)
```

Here's the project CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

project(CxxTemplate
  VERSION 0.1.0.0
  LANGUAGES C CXX
  DESCRIPTION "A project containing the essentials for other projects"
)
set(CxxTemplate_VENDOR "Aron Rubin")
set(PROJECT_VENDOR "${CxxTemplate_VENDOR}")


set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules")


if(POLICY CMP0074)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
endif()

find_package(GTest)
if(GTEST_FOUND)
set(Gtest_FOUND TRUE)
endif()
if(GTest_FOUND)
include(GoogleTest)
endif()

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)

include(CheckIncludeFiles)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES(sys/prctl.h HAVE_SYS_PRCTL_H)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(CxxTemplate
  src/CxxTemplate.cpp  
)

target_link_libraries(CxxTemplate
  PUBLIC Threads::Threads
)

include(FeatureSummary)
feature_summary(WHAT ALL)

# include(DumpProps)
# print_target_properties(diva)
# include(DumpVariables)
# dump_all_variables()
```

Here are the error messages:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:18: multiple definition of `main'; src\CxxTemplate.o:C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../src/CxxTemplate.cpp:32: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:11: undefined reference to `testing::Test::Test()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:11: undefined reference to `testing::Test::~Test()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:14: undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o: in function `TestBody':
C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:14: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:14: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:14: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:14: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:19: undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:516: undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o: in function `GetSetUpCaseOrSuite':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:516: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:516: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:516: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:531: undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o: in function `GetTearDownCaseOrSuite':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:531: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:531: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:531: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:C:\Users\mkkek\Documents\koodi\cppkirja\Advanced-CPlusPlus\Lesson1\Exercise01\project\CxxTemplate\Debug/../tests/CanTest.cpp:13: undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:CanTest.cpp:(.rdata+0x210): undefined reference to `testing::Test::SetUp()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:CanTest.cpp:(.rdata+0x218): undefined reference to `testing::Test::TearDown()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:CanTest.cpp:(.rdata+0x278): undefined reference to `testing::Test::SetUp()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o:CanTest.cpp:(.rdata+0x280): undefined reference to `testing::Test::TearDown()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o: in function `RUN_ALL_TESTS()':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/gtest.h:2473: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/gtest.h:2473: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o: in function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/gtest.h:1528: undefined reference to `testing::AssertionSuccess()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: tests\CanTest.o: in function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtest/gtest.h:1511: undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
```

I'd appreciate any help, as I'm not a C++ expert.

Comment: As far as I understand, you put the tests into `tests` executable. But the errors are from building `CxxTemplate` executable, which contains not only `src/CxxTemplate.cpp`, but `CanTest.cpp` too. Your project is messed somehow... Oh, according to your answer, it is not a CMake project which is actually built. Nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Eclipse as the IDE. I had simply forgotten to specify the builder in the project settings, so Eclipse tried to build the project with `g++`.

This helped:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can incorporate the building of the GTest library (from source) directly into your `CMake` configuration, as suggested by the official Google documentation: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project.

In other words, create a new file called `CMakeLists.txt.in`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

And then in your existing `CMakeLists.txt` file, include this snippet:

```
# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# The gtest/gtest_main targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
  include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()

# Now simply link against gtest or gtest_main as needed. Eg
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND example)

## Remainder of your project config...
```

Placing your test code in `example.cpp` should make them executable via `example.exe` once built.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue using eclipse. Mine was due to not linking the google test libraries which can be found in the lib folder of google test build directory.

[Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tsn8.png)